# Is there a native support for geojson in Couch DB 2.0

Tags: couchdb, geospatial, geojson

I have installed couchdb 2.0 on cent OS. I was wondering if any additional tools are needed to store and query geojson documents ? Do I have to install geocouch as well ? If so, how do  I install geocouch over couchdb 2.0 ?

Comment: Did you end up in any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Despite [GeoCouch is part of the CouchDB 2.0 documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/config/intro.html), [its developer's website](http://vmx.cx/cgi-bin/blog/index.cgi/goodbye-couchbase%3A2016-07-04%3Aen%2CCouchbase%2CGeoCouch) states it does not yet work with CouchDB 2.0.

Instead you may want to have a look at Cloudant Lab's [easton](https://github.com/cloudant-labs/easton) and [hastings](https://github.com/cloudant-labs/hastings).

Answer (score 2):

As almereyda answered Cloudant Lab's eastong and hastings will let you do geospatial indexes for CouchDB 2.0+. Since it was pretty hard to get up and running with those tools I created a Docker image for that.

You can find the docker image at https://hub.docker.com/r/kontrollanten/couchdb-hastings/. You should be up and running within some minutes. Be aware that huge databases may take some time for the first query (since CouchDB is creating the indexes upon query).